# NSUserDefaults display date and data in the tableView

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdate, tableview, nsuserdefaults

In the FirstViewController of my survey app I have NSMutableArray that contains data (strings). I've also created date varibale. Here's code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformater=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformater setDateFormat:@"EEEE,dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm a"];

NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
NSString *currentDate=[dateformater stringFromDate:today];
```

Now I want with the help of NSUserDefaults save data from the array and also save date variable when the  survey has been taken and display it  in the SecondViewController's tableview (first user can see date of the survey and then by tapping the date - data from array).

I know how NSUSerDefaults work but I don't know how to put array by date variable to be shown in the SecondViewController. Can anyone help me on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AppDelegate.h` file just declare variable...

```
NSUserDefaults  *userDefaults;
NSMutableArray *arrDate;
```

after...

In `AppDelegate.m` Fille in `applicationDidFinishLonching:` Method

```
    userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"arrDate"];
    if (dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch != nil) {
        NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch];
        if (oldSavedArray != nil)
            arrDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
        else
            arrDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } else {
        arrDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [arrDate retain];
```

after that when you want to insert,update or delete Data from this UserDefaults Use Bellow Code...

for Delete record from array

```
[appDelegate.arrDate removeObjectAtIndex:Index];/// give the integer value instead of Index
```

and this is for add record in array..

```
[appDelegate.arrDate addObject:currentDate];///add value or add date here
```

after in final save this modification in array just archive like bellow..

```
NSData *data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:appDelegate.arrDate];
[appDelegate.userDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"arrDate"];
[appDelegate.userDefaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `NSDictionary` with the date and data object:

`NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentDate], @"date", @"yourData", @"data", nil];`

Then put it in the `NSUserDefault` using:

```
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourDictionary forKey:@"item1"];
```

This will store a single data to NSUserDefault.

You can retrieve the object by using:

```
NSDictionary * dictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"item1"];
```

Now you will get the date using `[dictionary objectForKey:@"date"];` and data using : `[dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];`